# Pass a value from TeamBuild to MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, build, build-automation, tfsbuild

I have a build that is running in TFS TeamBuild.  I want to pass a property from that to the MSBuild that is run for each Project built by the TFSBuild.proj.

Example:

**TFSBuild.proj**

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <Version>0.0.0.0</Version>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="BuildNumberOverrideTarget" 
        DependsOnTargets="AfterInitializeWorkspace">

  <!--Code that loads the version from a file (removed).-->

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--Save off the version.-->
    <Version>$(TxCompleteVersion)</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**MyWIXProjectFile.wixproj**

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <!--If Version is defined then use that.  
   Else just use all zeros to show that this is a developer built version-->
  <CurrentVersion Condition="'$(Version)' == ''" >0.0.0.0</CurrentVersion>
  <CurrentVersion Condition="'$(Version)' != ''" >$(Version)</CurrentVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<Message Condition="'$(Version)' == ''" 
         Text="Version info is empty (i.e. a developer build).  Version set to $(CurrentVersion)"/>

</Target>
```

When the MyWixProjectFile.wixproj gets built the message showing that the $(Version) is blank gets printed every time.

Is there someway that I can get the project file to see the TFSBuild.proj properties?

Vaccano

Comment: You have verified that the Version in TFSBuild.proj is not blank correct?

Comment: Yes I have.  It is used in many other places and it correct all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done via the properties metadata in the SolutionToBuild tag.  For example:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)\ChangeThisOne.sln">
      <Targets></Targets>
      <Properties>Change=True</Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>
    <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)\ChangeThisToo.sln">
      <Targets></Targets>
      <Properties>Change=True</Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>
    <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)\DontChangeThis.sln">
      <Targets></Targets>
      <Properties>Don'tChange=False</Properties>
    </SolutionToBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert in Wix but I did find this and thought you could give it a try.

[Setting properties for WiX in MSBuild](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/setting-properties-for-wix-in-msbuild/)

Comment: Sadly this does not help me.  I already have a process to go from MSBuild to WIX.  It is getting from TeamBuild to MSBuild (at the project level) that has me stuck!

Thanks for the post though
Vaccano

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

Use MSBuild to directly call MyWIXProjectFile.wixproj and pass Version as property

Option 2

Abstract out build of wix out to its own selft contained script and then use MSBuild to call directly and passing all necessary properties. I have blog with full implementation doing this at http://blog.newagesolution.net/2008/06/how-to-use-msbuild-and-wix-to-msi.html that might be of interest to you.